# Possible to check if a website is open in browser from java

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Is it possible to check if a website is already opened in the default browser from a java program? I need my program to open a specific website before doing some other stuff. So is it possible to check whether this website is already open?

EDIT:
Ok, i'll try til explain the situation a little further. So i want to download some files from a webpage (http://aula.au.dk/main/document/document.php?cidReq=IMFFOUANAE12). When you click a file you're redirected to some file destinations where you can download it. My program list all these files, and then when you click a filename the browser opens the url that will redirect you to the download of that specific file. My problem is then, if the url i linked above isn't open i get an SQL-error from the website. Apparantly this error only show when the above url isn't open i an tab. So if i download a file, close the browser, try to download a new i get the problem. But as below, it seems cookies can help me out.

I'm not that in to all this http, website kinda stuff.

Regards
Jesper

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to do the thing that you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is possible, you can open Default browser by using Desktop class. Or you can do

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(new String[]{"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "-new-window", "example.com"});
```

Why should you worry even if your page is already opened ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but even if you try to open same page browser will keep the session of old page.It will be tracked using jsessionid.

Please check the links using cookies you can do

http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-cookie-example-in-servlet/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-session-tracking.htm

Comment: Ohh, see my edit. It seems cookies is where i should look! Thanks, i'll try looking into that!

Comment: are you using applets in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible purely because Java has no way of knowing whether browsers are open and what browsers are in use. If such a feature were to be implemented it would literally require natively hooking into the api of every browser. Something which while can be done would only support the browsers you choose it to (Firefox,Chrome,IE,Safari,Opera) etc etc, but it requires directly interfacing with the native C libraries, something outside of the scope of this and certainly overkill for such a trivial feature.